# Error bundle install sqlite3 on Mac OS 10.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I have the following error while try to install sqlite3 gem using bundler,

```
Installing sqlite3 1.3.8 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/FS_RailsSampleApp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160911-50928-1ikcevl.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/FS_RailsSampleApp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.8/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/FS_RailsSampleApp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/FS_RailsSampleApp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3
make "DESTDIR="
compiling backup.c
compiling database.c
compiling exception.c
compiling sqlite3.c
compiling statement.c
statement.c:261:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'RBIGNUM' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      if (RBIGNUM_LEN(value) * SIZEOF_BDIGITS <= 8) {
          ^
./sqlite3_ruby.h:16:24: note: expanded from macro 'RBIGNUM_LEN'
#define RBIGNUM_LEN(x) RBIGNUM(x)->len
                       ^
statement.c:261:11: error: member reference type 'int' is not a pointer
      if (RBIGNUM_LEN(value) * SIZEOF_BDIGITS <= 8) {
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./sqlite3_ruby.h:16:36: note: expanded from macro 'RBIGNUM_LEN'
#define RBIGNUM_LEN(x) RBIGNUM(x)->len
                       ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
statement.c:261:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SIZEOF_BDIGITS'
      if (RBIGNUM_LEN(value) * SIZEOF_BDIGITS <= 8) {
                               ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [statement.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/FS_RailsSampleApp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/FS_RailsSampleApp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.8/gem_make.out
```

I do have **sqlite3** install via Home Brew, and `which sqlite3` shows `/usr/bin/sqlite3`.

The snippet below is the output in `mkmf.log` file,

```
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void sqlite3_initialize();
14: int t(void) { sqlite3_initialize(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... -------------------- yes

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3_backup_init'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_backup_init; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_backup_init; return !p; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void sqlite3_backup_init();
14: int t(void) { sqlite3_backup_init(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3_column_database_name'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_column_database_name; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_column_database_name; return !p; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_column_database_name", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-cb897c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void sqlite3_column_database_name();
14: int t(void) { sqlite3_column_database_name(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3_enable_load_extension'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_enable_load_extension; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_enable_load_extension; return !p; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_enable_load_extension", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-be2319.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void sqlite3_enable_load_extension();
14: int t(void) { sqlite3_enable_load_extension(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3_load_extension'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_load_extension; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_load_extension; return !p; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_load_extension", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-324aa9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void sqlite3_load_extension();
14: int t(void) { sqlite3_load_extension(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... -------------------- yes

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3_open_v2'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_open_v2; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_open_v2; return !p; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void sqlite3_open_v2();
14: int t(void) { sqlite3_open_v2(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... -------------------- yes

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_prepare_v2; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_prepare_v2; return !p; }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib    -lsqlite3  -lruby.2.3.0 -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void sqlite3_prepare_v2();
14: int t(void) { sqlite3_prepare_v2(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_type: checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... -------------------- yes

"clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe   -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <sqlite3.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: typedef sqlite3_int64 conftest_type;
7: int conftestval[sizeof(conftest_type)?1:-1];
/* end */

--------------------

have_type: checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... -------------------- yes

"clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe   -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <sqlite3.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: typedef sqlite3_uint64 conftest_type;
7: int conftestval[sizeof(conftest_type)?1:-1];
/* end */

--------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple versions of Ruby on your Mac 2.3.0 and 2.3.1. You are advised to include sqlite3 locally in the Gemfile of your project and then run `bundle install` from there